# How can I expose my WSDL objects in my WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, datacontractserializer

I have a WCF Service, which is acting as a proxy for the 3rd party service.

I've added a Service Reference to a 3rd party WSDL endpoint, and now have a number of objects in my reference.cs file that I wish to expose from my WCF Server, that can be consumed by requests to my service.

For example;

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2046.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
public partial class OTA_HotelAvailRQ : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   private string echoTokenField;

   private System.DateTime timeStampField;

   private bool timeStampFieldSpecified;

   private bool targetFieldSpecified;

   private decimal versionField;

   private bool availRatesOnlyField;

   private bool availRatesOnlyFieldSpecified;

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
   public string EchoToken
   {
       get
       {
           return this.echoTokenField;
       }
       set
       {
           this.echoTokenField = value;
           this.RaisePropertyChanged("EchoToken");
       }
   }

   /// <remarks/>
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
   public System.DateTime TimeStamp
   {
       get
       {
           return this.timeStampField;
       }
       set
       {
           this.timeStampField = value;
          this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStamp");
       }
   }

   /// <remarks/>
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
   public bool TimeStampSpecified
   {
       get
       {
           return this.timeStampFieldSpecified;
       }
       set
       {
           this.timeStampFieldSpecified = value;
           this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStampSpecified");
       }
   }

   /// <remarks/>
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
   public decimal Version
   {
       get
       {
           return this.versionField;
       }
       set
       {
           this.versionField = value;
           this.RaisePropertyChanged("Version");
       }
   }

   /// <remarks/>
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
   public bool AvailRatesOnly
   {
       get
       {
           return this.availRatesOnlyField;
       }
       set
       {
           this.availRatesOnlyField = value;
           this.RaisePropertyChanged("AvailRatesOnly");
       }
   }

   /// <remarks/>
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
   public bool AvailRatesOnlySpecified
   {
       get
       {
           return this.availRatesOnlyFieldSpecified;
       }
       set
       {
           this.availRatesOnlyFieldSpecified = value;
           this.RaisePropertyChanged("AvailRatesOnlySpecified");
       }
   }

   public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
       if ((propertyChanged != null))
       {
           propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is

> Type '' with data contract name '' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

The only way I've managed to expose these objects is by decorating them with [DataContract] and the properties with [DataMember].

However, the problem I have is that my reference.cs contains a lot of objects, and I'd rather find an automated way of doing it.

Any advice ?

Comment: So is your service acting as a proxy?

Comment: Yes, in essence my service is requesting data from the 3rd party service, and I'm wanting to expose these objects